# Windows/opengl glext.h build issue

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

So I'm trying to bring a c++ project using Qt and OpenGL written and compiled on a Linux machine over to my Windows 7 machine at home, but I'm running into some difficulty.  First I learned that some gl things (like GL_TEXTURE0) were no longer defined because gl.h doesn't define them for windows.  Also, the glext.h that I have does not define some functions like glActiveTexture.  Both of these issues I found could be solved by bringing in a newer glext.h.

My most immediate issue seems to be that I'm not bringing it in correctly.  If I do:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_LEGACY      //should prevent old glext.h from being included
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES  //should make glActiveTexture be defined 
#include <qgl.h>                 
#include "glext.h"           //local up-to-date glext.h
#include <QGLShaderProgram>
```

then make tells me that I have undefined references to glActiveTexture.  If I include QGLShaderProgram before glext.h, then I still have that problem, but make also warns me that I am redefining quite a few things that are defined in both QGLShaderProgram and glext, so I know the latter file is being included.  Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, it's almost always a bad idea (and usually won't work) to just download an arbitrary header file from the internet to replace one of your system headers.  OpenGL is a little bit of a special case since it's implemented by graphics drivers, so the typical way of accessing it on Windows (without Qt) is to get pointers to the functions at runtime.  An extension library like GLEW makes this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You are on a right path, but like Nick Meyer wrote, you need to get pointers to the functions at runtime.

There is a nice and clean example already in Qt installation directory, at least since 4.6. Check ["Boxes"](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/demos-boxes.html) from "demos"-directory. There is [glextensions.h](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/demos-boxes-glextensions-h.html)/[cpp](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/demos-boxes-glextensions-cpp.html) that takes care of those required functions in Qt-way, using Qt's [QGLContext](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qglcontext.html) etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lazy like me, just hop over to
http://glew.sourceforge.net
and use that, no need to fiddle around with different header files and manually retrieving function pointers. It's as simple as

```
/* in every source file using OpenGL */
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

and

```
/* for each OpenGL context */
if( createGLContext(...) == SUCCESSFULL )
    glewInit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt you should probably use qmake - and just add

> QT += opengl

to your qmake project file.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually have been using qmake(sorry I should have been more clear).  Adding opengl to my project config didn't seem to do it either.  I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the includes... This project compiled fine on linux (with the functions missing from glext declared as c-style functions)

Comment: @mprice - small edit, sorry. But really a proper Qt install should take care of the includes for you. I have Qt + opengl projects that compile on windows and linux with no header changes. For non-qt stuff in the past, sometimes I've needed `#include <GL/blah.h>` on some platforms and not others.